# Age of Alpha Piscium B

Tags: star

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Piscium, the age of Piscium B is 331 Myr and   the Surface Gravity of 4.01 ± 0.14  it cites the link :- https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/483/2/2300/5184501?login=false

When we view the table, https://academic.oup.com/view-large/127773013 , we see it says the SG is 4.01 and that the age of said star is 8.52 Gyr.

Therefore,

```
a) Wikipedia is wrong
b) 8.52 Gyr is not the age but represents something else and where in the document is 331 derived from?
c) I'm missing something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age in that paper is given as $\log t/{\rm Gyr} = 8.52$. This is a typo. It should be $\log t/{\rm yr}=8.52$, which corresponds to 331 Myr. i.e. There is no discrepancy once the obvious typo has been accounted for.

Comment: How do you derive 330 from 8.52?  What formula should I apply to get 330 using non-scientific formula, i.e. something that I can use a non-scienific calculator to work out.

Comment: I ultimately want to turn it into a computer formula so scientific notation won't help me with notation.

Comment: $\log_{10} (331\times 10^6)= 8.52$ @MiscellaneousUser Or $10^{8.52}=331\times10^6$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I get the figures and am happy.  Will apply the formula to the others.